# NGINX refused to connect localhost on CentOS VM

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, centos

I am running Centos7 on a VM as a guesthost on a MAC. I have followed the following tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-centos-7

I have two network adapters running one NAT and the other is the host only adapter which have the following settings:

NAT Adapter

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=a81126f4-7714-442d-91e0-0f4032512efb
DEVICE=enp0s3
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
ONBOOT=yes
```

Host Only Adapter

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=enp0s8
IPADDR=192.168.56.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

So when I try to connect to my NGINX webpage by going on http://192.168.63.2 on my main system it states connection is refused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am hoping that you followed proper document ! Kindly check firewall connection. Use below command to check

```
# systemctl status firewalld
```

If it is running

Kindly check below command check if 80 port or http services listed or not

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
```

Comment: I went through the firewall commands and it worked. thanks.